# json must be a str not bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

def main(target_db):

```
# get available logs 

output = subprocess.Popen(['aws','rds', 'describe-db-log-files', '--db-instance-identifier', target_db],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

dict_output = json.loads(output)
log_file_names = map(lambda l:l['LogFileName'], dict_output['DescribeDBLogFiles'])

mkdir_p('logs/error')

# aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier prod-api --log-file-name error/postgresql.log.2015-04-20-18 --output text > logs/error/postgresql.log.2015-04-20-18
for log_file_name in log_file_names:
    content = subprocess.Popen(['aws','rds', 'download-db-log-file-portion', '--db-instance-identifier', target_db, '--log-file-name', log_file_name, '--output', 'text'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    with open('logs/%s' % log_file_name, 'wb') as fw:
        fw.write(content)
```

I am getting an error json must be str not bytes while running the script in line where it loads as a json object  (dict_output = json.loads(output)).

Comment: what is the `python version` you are using and what is the `aws cli output format` you have configured?

Comment: It is a better practice to leverage boto3 library to do your operations instead of creating subproces: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.download_db_log_file_portion and http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_log_files

Comment: python version is 3.4.3

Comment: i am not using boto because it returns only portion of log files not whole log files it returns only max upto 1 mb file

Answer (score 0):

First try to print type like that:

`print type(output)`

If it isn't string try to convert it to string using this:

`output = str(output)` or `dict_output = json.loads(str(output))`

Hope this will help.